# Registering a receiver inside a class which extends NotificationListenerService

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand the `NotificationListenerService` a bit better. I have created a `NotificationListenerService` which listens to notifications (so far so good).

My understanding is that this service will be bound to the system service and basically it will run all the time in the background, of course it's methods will be only called when there is a change in the notifications. 
SO I thought I will be "smart" and since we cannot use implicit intent filters in the manifest file any more, I though I will register my filters here, something like:

```
static PlayBackQue playbackQue=new PlayBackQue();
.................................................
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter ();
filter.addAction ("android.app.action.ENTER_CAR_MODE");
filter.addAction ("android.app.action.EXIT_CAR_MODE");
registerReceiver(playbackQue,filter);
```

However I do see that the `NotificationListenerService` actually does call the `onDestory` method and the logs complains about leak (since I'm not actually un-registering the listener).

My receiver continues to work without problems, however I'm confident that this is not good.

What I struggle to fully understand is the exact lifecycle of the `NotificationListenerService`.

Also if the system services holds a reference to my class which extends the `NotificationListenerService`, is it safe to assume that it will hold the reference of the static variable as well, in which case my broadcast receiver will be remembered?

I know I can (maybe should) create a foreground service, but my app needs to access notifications anyway so I will like to avoid to have another foregraound service running, just to implement 2 intentfilters. Sadly Google have removed the CAR mode filters from the implicit filter list, and currently there is no real way to detect when the phone is in car mode. Job Scheduler is not a real option because it's not guarantee to run immediately and there is no appropriate schedule you can use anyway....

Answer (score 1):

NotificationListenerService lifecycle starts with onListenerConnected() and ends with onListenerDisconnected(). It should be safe to register your receiver when connected and unregister it when disconnected. I don't know much about the PlayBackQue receiver, but it's generally not a good idea to use static variables. It's better to make it an instance variable of the service. While your service is connected, you can assume the system will keep a reference to it. Once disconnected, you can't make any assumptions about that and you wouldn't want any static variables hanging around. Unless you need that receiver to stick around in which case it probably doesn't belong in the NotificationListenerService.

Comment: Thanks, the PlayBackQue is my own class, I know about the onListenerConnected() and onListenerDisconnected(), the onListenerDisconnected() never get's called, however the onDestory() does get called, and at that point I do see logs complaining about it.

Comment: You're granting notification access permission to your app correct? As soon as you do it should connect. When you revoke notification access, the service will disconnect. It's odd that onDestroy() is getting called without being disconnected first.  Does it ever connect?

Comment: Yes it does connect and it works absolutely fine. It never disconnects (well unless I remove the notification access rights) so i did find it strange that onDestory gets called, hence asking here....

Answer (score -1):

The safest thing to do is to 
       - call registerReceiver() in onCreate() function of notification listener service
       - call unregisterReceived() in onDestroy()function of noticationListenerService.

I have done this in the past and the app worked without any leaks.

Comment: Raju, thanks but if you read the question is about NotificationListenerService class. I know how to do it normally, however the notificationlistener is a special case, onDestory should not even be called in the first place, or at least that's what I'm trying to work out.